# Loop through two files Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, loops

What's the neatest way to iterate over two files simultaneously, so that if line 57 in file_1 == 'x' then treat line 57 in file_2 this way?

My code below isn't working, but I know there is a simple solution out there...

```
@blue = []
@red = []

file_1 = File.open('index.txt', 'r')
file_2 = File.open('index2.txt', 'r')

for item, line in file_1, file_2
   @blue << line if item == "blue"
   @red << line if item == "red"
end

file_1.close
file_2.close
```

Comment: What should happen if the files differ in length (= number of lines)?

Comment: I can't quite follow your loop here, probably my ignorance of Ruby but there you are; is `item` the line from `file_1` and `line` the line from `file_2`?

Comment: @glenatron yes that was my basic premise

Comment: @FrankSchmitt good point, i discovered a slight discrepancy now. I guess I will do a try / rescue to recover any errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **never** a good practice to read the entire file in a go and to place that in a variable.

For your question, which needs concurrent reading of two files, I will suggest this (which doesn't require any sort of space overhead):

```
@blue = []
@red = []
#make the files enumerable. 
file_1 = File.open('index.txt', 'r').to_enum
file_2 = File.open('index2.txt', 'r').to_enum

loop do
  #access next line in each file with .next
  item = file_1.next
  line = file_2.next
  @blue << line if item.eql?('blue')
  @red  << line if item.eql?('red')
end

file_1.close
file_2.close
```

[`to_enum`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/to_enum) when called on object, makes it enumerable and equips it several enumerator capabilities. `#next` is one of those built in method.

The code above reads a line from each file one by one; loop will terminate as soon as any of the file is out of **next** input.

Comment: You mean, reading two files(of say, 2GB each) and storing it in some variable is recommendable? Even if the file is not that big, what if it is supplied with one such thing?

Comment: No, reading in two files of 2 gig each is not generally recommendable (though it might still be no problem). Neither is ~1 billion file reads. In that case the program should probably be using sql or some other database solution. That doesn't answer why it is **never** good practice; if the files are not unrealistically large it's fine.

Comment: I like the use of `to_enum` but this doesn't do what the question asks. This only calls `next` on `file_2` when it finds 'blue' or 'red' in `file_1`. I believe the intent is for the lines in the two files to be zipped together.

Comment: @Max : Thanks for bringing this in notice; Have updated the code :). Now, on each iteration, we acquire next line from each file; and if 'blue' or 'red' is found in line from `file_1`, we add line from `file_2` to the corresponding instance var.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard You answered it. "If the files are not unrealistically large it's fine". Maybe, ~1 billion file reads is better than acquiring IO to read big files(and then to pump them to primary memory) and wait for it to get done with the reading process. :)

Comment: @kiddorails My only other suggestion would be to `zip` the enumerators, but I'm not sure if that comes with a performance hit. It would certainly simplify the loop, however.

Comment: @Max I wrote an Enumerator object here - http://pastie.org/8438092 . How is it? On terms of your suggestion? :)

Comment: That's alright, but I suggested `zip` for succinctness. For example `file_1.zip(file_2) do |item, line|`

Comment: I don't think it is a **never** situation.  Let's say that you have a program where people use it to connect to a remote server.  You have them store the API key into a file, read it in one go, and store it in a variable.  You could do so in a database, but consumers often don't have a database laying around, and if they do, don't know what do with it.  My advice is to exactly read that file in one go and store it in a variable.

Comment: file_1.close and file_2.close will break `undefined method `close' for #<Enumerator: #<File:old.txt>:each> (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there's a better way, but it works to call [`IO#readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-readlines) on the files and [`zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) them like so:

```
for item, line in file_1.readlines.zip(file_2.readlines)
```

As long as the files aren't too large (that is, *very* large) there should be no problem with reading them in their entirety. You may want to check that the files have the same number of lines beforehand to avoid unexpected behavior.

Comment: Define 'very large'.  If my system has 640k of memory, then very large is not very large at all, being less than a meg.  If it has 32 gigs of ram, then very large is another thing entirely.  "Very large" is not likely very helpful.

Comment: If one is working on something, which can be used by general user out there, he should take in account that the file is not 'very large' to be read in that system. This is hypothetical; but again, this is something too relative to define.

Comment: @vgoff "Very large" means very large relative to the system it's running on. It's subjective, but I guess you'll know it when you see it. I doubt OP is intending this for use on files with a million lines, though even so any modern system could handle it fine. Also, if your system has 640k I doubt it can run Ruby.

Comment: So when you say very large, you are saying "a file that is able to fit into available memory"?   If you state so, then it becomes very clear.

Comment: Alternatively I used `fd0.readlines.zip(fd1.readlines, fd2.readlines, fd3.readlines).each do |line0, line1, line2, line3 |`

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to create an array from each file using `File.readlines()` then operating on those arrays rather than trying to work with the file data directly. Something like this, perhaps:

```
@blue = []
@red = []

file_1 = File.open('index.txt', 'r')
file_2 = File.open('index2.txt', 'r')

red_vs_blue = file_1.readlines()
lines = file_2.readlines()

red_vs_blue.zip(lines)

red_vs_blue.each do | item, line |
  @blue << line if item == "blue"
  @red << line if item == "red"
end
```